# Help to find out what component is being used

Tags: objective-c

I'm a beginner with Objective-C and I have to create something similar to the one on this image but I don't know what are the components on the top bar.

[image: I just need to know what component is being used on the top]

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: at least leave a comment for the -1, plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a navigation bar but I think a customized view with customized buttons are what it actually is.

Comment: if it is customized, how to program the back button?

Comment: It depends on how you get here. If you add the current vein onto the stack, on **TouchUpInside** of the back button, just pop the view and you're back.